# Modify all occurences of a tag

Tags: support, tags, plurals

On [Worldbuilding](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2360/tags-cleaning-singular-vs-plural), we realised that a few tags would need some modification, namely uniformizing the plural/singular type. Is there a way to modify all occurences of a given tag, or should be manually edit them one by one?

Due to the number of modifications needed, we'd rather avoid setting up synonyms for all of them.